# Python Clickatell ошибка

Tags: python, webclient

При отправки сообщения через Clickatell происходит ошибка в ApiKey.
Самое сообщение в итоге доставляется, но вот код заканчивает работу с ошибкой
[image: Ошибка]

```
from clickatell.http import Http

clickatell = Http('apiKey')
clickatell.sendMessage(number, '12345')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from clickatell.http import Http
clickatell = Http(name, pass, api)
result=clickatell.sendMessage(number, '12345')
for it in result:
   print(result)
```

выведет в том числе и отчёт об ошибках